How to verify whether user successfully sign up or login in wordpress using digits plugin?
I need to add some js code to digits plugin and then send data to google analytics. While using digits plugin, there are default forms for login and sign up and I am using these forms. I need to send data to google analytics when user successfully registers or logs into to website. The problem is that I don't know in which php file authentication is made, If I learn that, I can add the js code there. Which file needs to be edited?
If someone have experience of using this plugin, their help would be appreciated. I don't know the structure of this plugin's code.

You don't need to change the plugin's own codes.
The Digits is a standard plugin, so it performs some actions in your desired situations, such as:

after successful signup:

woocommerce_created_customer

digits_user_created



after successful login:

wp_login



You can add a flag to the user session in the hook and output your JavaScript code on the first page the user will encounter after redirection.

Thanks for the answer. The point is I need to track the type of sign in or signup which can be either OTP or Password. These types of actions are not provided in the mentioned sources.

If you want this, you can use the "digits_user_created" hook for detecting OTP signups. Also, you need to manipulate the plugin and add your own hook (such as "digits_user_login") to detect OTP sign ins. (In this case, you need to disable plugin update and create an issue to fix it in the future.)
